# how to Add as well as Subtract  in one single sql query based on startTime

Tags: mysql, sql

IF **startTime=11.30** AND **endTime=12.30**

if the user gives the start time as 11.20 it should subtract the time by ten minutes[10] in both startTime and endTime and if the start time is 11.50 it should add twenty minutes[20]

How to achieve this in one single sql query

```
 output: if the startTime =11.20
 startTime=11.20
 endTime=12.20


 output : if the startTime =11.50
 startTime=11.50
 endTime=12.50
```

Comment: There are many useful functions - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Your examples don't seem to match your description...

Comment: something like adding and subtracting in a case query

Comment: @Dems i meant the query should be able to add as well as subtract based on startTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description and examples still don't match, so I can only give a very generalised example based on your comment...

How to add or subtract an interval based on a CASE statement...

```
CASE
  WHEN MINUTE(startTime) = 20 THEN DATE_ADD(startTime, -10 MINUTES)
  WHEN MINUTE(startTime) = 50 THEN DATE_ADD(startTime,  20 MINUTES)
  ELSE NULL
END AS newStartTime,
CASE
  WHEN MINUTE(startTime) = 20 THEN DATE_ADD(endTime, -10 MINUTES)
  WHEN MINUTE(startTime) = 50 THEN DATE_ADD(endTime,  20 MINUTES)
  ELSE NULL
END AS newEndTime
```

You can have as many `WHEN` clauses as you like, changing the `MINUTE(startTime) = 20` conditions to anything you like, and having whatever you want in the `THEN` clause.  Then, if you have a case that doesn't match any `WHEN` clause, put your desired ouput in the `ELSE` clause.

You'll need to repeat the logic for both the `startTime` and `endTime` fields.

Comment: it might be the time which the user might give not sure he wil give 10 or 20 min...but thanks for the solution